# Unable to ssh to EC2 instance after some works. Permission denied (public key)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

Yesterday, I made one instance of ubuntu-server on Amazon EC2.
Actually **I could ssh to this instance**, and I set up my developing enviroment on this instance.

But after reboot the instance, I got an error of ssh. I'm confused because this command and local machine's enviroment are same! Of course, private key is also same.

```
$ ssh -i "xxx.pem" ubuntu@xxxxxx
Permission denied (publie key).
```

So I doubt that I've edited /etc/rc.local to start my service, so I cleared this configuration with a rescue instance. Actually I could succeed to edit the instance's file with the rescue instance and mounting volume without ssh.
In this rescue instance, I could use same private key (.pem) and Elastic IP.

**environments**

- ubuntu-trusty-14.04-amd64-server-20150325
- t2.micro
- using EIP

**security group**

- SSH, TCP, 22, 0.0.0.0/0

**instance status on console**

- 2/2 check is ok

  - system status check: ok
  - instance status check: ok

**system log**

I also checked system log on web console, I coudn't find errors.

```
 * Stopping Mount filesystems on boot[74G[ OK ]

 * Starting Signal sysvinit that local filesystems are mounted[74G[ OK ]

 * Starting flush early job output to logs[74G[ OK ]

 * Stopping Failsafe Boot Delay[74G[ OK ]

 * Starting System V initialisation compatibility[74G[ OK ]

 * Stopping flush early job output to logs[74G[ OK ]

 * Starting D-Bus system message bus[74G[ OK ]

 * Starting SystemD login management service[74G[ OK ]

 * Starting system logging daemon[74G[ OK ]

 * Starting early crypto disks...       [80G 
[74G[ OK ]

 * Starting Handle applying cloud-config[74G[ OK ]

 * Starting Bridge file events into upstart[74G[ OK ]

Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd

 * Starting AppArmor profiles       [80G 
[74G[ OK ]

 * Setting up X socket directories...       [80G 
[74G[ OK ]

 * Stopping System V initialisation compatibility[74G[ OK ]

 * Starting System V runlevel compatibility[74G[ OK ]

open-vm-tools: not starting as this is not a VMware VM

landscape-client is not configured, please run landscape-config.

 * Starting xinetd daemon[74G[ OK ]

 * Starting ACPI daemon[74G[ OK ]

 * Starting save kernel messages[74G[ OK ]

 * Starting configure network device security[74G[ OK ]

 * Starting OpenSSH server[74G[ OK ]

 * Starting regular background program processing daemon[74G[ OK ]

 * Starting deferred execution scheduler[74G[ OK ]

 * Stopping save kernel messages[74G[ OK ]

 * Stopping CPU interrupts balancing daemon[74G[ OK ]

 * Starting configure virtual network devices[74G[ OK ]

 * Starting automatic crash report generation[74G[ OK ]

 * Restoring resolver state...       [80G 
[74G[ OK ]

Cloud-init v. 0.7.5 running 'modules:config' at Tue, 15 Dec 2015 06:23:27 +0000. Up 6.40 seconds.

 * Stopping Handle applying cloud-config[74G[ OK ]

 * Stopping cold plug devices[74G[ OK ]

 * Stopping log initial device creation[74G[ OK ]

 * Starting enable remaining boot-time encrypted block devices[74G[ OK ]

 * Starting save udev log and update rules[74G[ OK ]

 * Stopping save udev log and update rules[74G[ OK ]

 * 

 * Stopping System V runlevel compatibility[74G[ OK ]

 * Starting execute cloud user/final scripts[74G[ OK ]

Cloud-init v. 0.7.5 running 'modules:final' at Tue, 15 Dec 2015 06:23:29 +0000. Up 7.81 seconds.
Cloud-init v. 0.7.5 finished at Tue, 15 Dec 2015 06:23:29 +0000. Datasource DataSourceEc2.  Up 7.86 seconds


Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS ip-10-0-0-17 ttyS0

ip-10-0-0-17 login:
```

Perhaps I dropped some important settings, could anyone give me hints for this trouble?

Comment: what is the output of ssh -v ?

Comment: what about `ssh -vvv your-host` ?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I've noticed that permission of home directory is set to 777. So I got an error, 'Permission denied'. After I set permission to 755 with rescue instance, I could ssh to this machine. I'm not sure why my home directory on ec2 is set to 777..